# How I can obtain a char * matrix?

Tags: c, xcode, matrix, char

I'm trying to obtain a char * matrix in C language, but runtime errors occurred to me. The following code shows how I've tried to do this. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong and why? I'm new in C programming, but I came from Java's and PHP's worlds. 
Thanks in advance for your interesting and help

```
int rows = 10;
int cols = 3;

//I create rows
char *** result = calloc(rows, sizeof(char **));

//I create cols
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    result[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof(char *));
}

//Load values into the matrix
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        result[i][j] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        if (NULL != result[i][j])
        {
            strcpy(result[i][j], "hello");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Print the matrix
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\t", result[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Ps: I'm using xCode with C99

The runtime error occurs here:

```
result[i][j] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

xCode returs me EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: You initialized `result` as an array of 10 `char**` elements. Then you filled the first 3 elements of this array with `char*` pointers, leaving the other 7 set to zero. Your runtime errors are occurring in the following nested loop, where you dereference all these null pointers and attempt to store text strings in them.

Comment: You're right, @squeamishossifrage. I inverted the concept. I'm beholden to you. Now all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    result[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof(char *));
}
```

should be this:

```
// -----------------here
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    result[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof(char *));
}
```

Unrelated: [Stop casting memory allocation functions in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). This:

```
result[i][j] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

should just be this:

```
result[i][j] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

I found it odd this was here, since you correctly did *not* cast your `calloc` results.

---

**Alternate Version: Variable Length Arrays (VLAs)**

You can cut out one of your allocation loops by exploiting VLAs if your platform supports them. If done, the code would reduce to allocating the entire matrix of `char*` with a single `calloc`. For example:

```
int main()
{
    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 3;

    // create rows
    char *(*result)[cols] = calloc(rows, sizeof(*result));

    // load values into the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
            if (NULL != result[i][j])
            {
                strcpy(result[i][j], "hello");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Print the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("%s\t", result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and all work. As I said to @squeamishossifrage I inverted the concept. I'm very grateful to you. Have a nice evening, you deserve it :))

Answer (score 0):

In first for loop you are allocating memory only for 3 rows and you are trying to access more than 3 rows in your last loop.